# Determine COM port to which a device locks

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I have a micro-controller (Arduino) and wish to determine automatically to which port the micro-controller locks to. The idea is not to have to correct the COM port manually for every app on every computer. Can this be done ? Thanks !

Comment: Normal framework or compact, micro? Maybe add some tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

- Micro-controller is an external hardware device
- User plugs the device into a random serial port (COM port)
- You want to know which COM port it's connected to

?

Also, you are talking about an old-style COM port, are you, not a USB?

Anyway if that is your question, the only way would be to:

- Open each COM port on the machine and send data through it, to see (if the micro-controller sends back the expected resonse) whether it's talking to the expected device (e.g. if the device were a modem you might try sending "[AT\r](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_and_Data_modes_%28modem%29)" and expect a modem to respond "OK", if there is a modem and if the modem is connected to that serial port).
- And/or write a device driver or a service to do just this, instead of an application.

Comment: Thanks ! i'll try to send to each COM port data to see if it's the controller i seek !